# Primera letra de una palabra en C

Tags: c, funciones

Necesito realizar un programa que saque la primera letra de una palabra a través de una función en C, sin usar características de Arrays.

Tengo este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char dimeLetra(char[]);

int main(){
  char palabra[20];
  char letra;
  printf("Introduce tu palabra: ");
  scanf("%s",&palabra);
  letra = dimeLetra(&palabra);
  printf("%c",letra);
}

char dimeLetra(char p[]){
  printf("%s",p);
  char l;
  strncpy(l,p,0);
  return l;
}
```

No consigo que la función `dimeLetra` me devuelva la primera letra de la palabra que le mando.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: a que te refieres con sin _"usar características de Arrays"_?

Comment: A que no puedo usar palabra[0] para sacar la primera letra. Debe ser con funciones de cadenas

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con tu código? Qué error sale o cómo se comporta? Por favor, procura hacer una pregunta que contenga todos los datos del problema.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo. Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char palabra[20];
int cantLetras = 2; // Elijo la cantidad de letras que deseo saber.(Izq a derecha)

  dimeLetra(char text[]){

   char buffer[512]; // Buffer para copiar

   strncpy(buffer,text,cantLetras);

   printf("\rPrimers 2 letras:\t%s",buffer); // Visualizacion de la cadena
}
int main()
{
    printf("Introduce tu palabra: ");
    scanf("%s",&palabra);

    dimeLetra(palabra);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La primera letra de una formación de caracteres en C, es el contenido del puntero de la formación:

```
char dimeLetra(char p[]){
  return *p;
}
```